# TFS - How to promote code to prod branch without merging

Tags: tfs

We have 3 TFS branches – dev, test, and prod.
TFS works well for us as source control as long as we check in and get latest often.  Then the merging is small and we can resolve any issues right away.   We know that if we don’t do this every day, then merging our code will be painful.

But by the time we are ready to promote to one of the other branches, there are huge changes in the code.  We don’t want to keep any of the code in the target branch, and we really do want an exact copy of the source version, not a merge.

We do like having the 3 branches so that change sets are kept for the complete set of changes in each deployment/promotion.

I don’t see a way in TFS to do this very common function.  I have been using two workarounds:

1. If only one user does the merging from one branch to the next, TFS really does copy all changes.  But it does not work if the user is different than the last user attempting the promotion, then TFS will merge the code.
2. I have checked out the whole solution of my local copy of the target branch.  Then done a file system copy of the source branch folder into the target branch folder.  Then checked in the solution.

Is there a right way?

Comment: Why are there huge differences between your branches? Dev should be QA+ and QA should be Prod+... You should never get conflicts pushing from Dev->QA->Prod. If you do your workflow is broken.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to merge is:-

1. Set up a shared workspace that contains both branches (if you don't already have one)
2. Get the latest `Target` branch code
3. Get the latest `Source` branch code
4. Merge from your `Source` to your `Target` using Latest Version and All Changes to a Specific Version
5. Submit your Changes to Source
6. To overwrite the target if you get conflicts, to ensure that the target is definately overwritten, Select Choose Source version at the conflict window

Comment: When I follow the steps in the answer above, I get a chance to merge the conflicts in the conflict window for only one file.  I also get many automatically resolved conflicts, which I do not want.  One example of an automated merge was that 3 new properties in a source branch class did not make it to the target branch.  I did not go so far as to submit the changes to source because I know it is missing some of the new code.

Is there a way to configure TFS to allow the choice to merge each conflict in a conflict window?

Comment: I see that there are many reasons for branching and merging which I will use in developing and testing a stable branch that is ready to be released to production.  I also need a safe way to take code that is ready for release and promote it as a copy, not a merge, following the principle of merge down, copy up.  If TFS does not provide a copy option, then I will continue to use a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is way late, but

My solution in this scenario

Prod -> Dev -> Test

(parent) -> (child) -> (grandchild)

When test is ready to be promoted, I do the following.

1. Delete Prod (This can be undone with rollback, but check-in)
2. Branch Test -> Prod (Use the same name a location as the old deleted version), so your new branch structure will be Dev -> Test -> Prod
3. Reparent Prod (new branch) to "none"
4. Reparent Dev to Prod
5. Delete Test
6. Branch Dev -> Test

When you look at the new branch hierarchy it will look the same as when you started but the code in prod will be the same as Test.

Comment: Please note the pending check outs and workspaces will go unchanged.